# How to "namespace" methods in Python class

Tags: python, class, namespaces

I want a class in Python with an interface like the following:

```
import myclass

client = myclass.Client("user", "password")

client.users.create("user1")
client.posts.create("user1", "Hello, World!")
```

Note that instead of just `create_user` or `create_post`, I want to specify the method using two dots: `users.create` / `posts.create`

I want this particular interface to mimic an HTTP API I'm trying to work with (which has endpoints like "/api/users/create" and "/api/posts/create")

If I define my class as follows in `myclass.py`:

```
class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, user, pass):
        self.user = user
        self.pass = pass
```

Then how do I create these dot-namespaced methods? My first thought is to create subclasses like so:

```
class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, user, pass):
        self.user = user
        self.pass = pass
        self.users = ClientUserAPI()
        self.posts = ClientPostAPI()

class ClientUserAPI(object):
    def create(self):
        # Do some cURL magic

class ClientPostAPI(object):
    def create(self):
        # Do some cURL magic
```

However if I do this, then I run into one of two problems (one serious, the other just philosophical / ideological)

1. If `ClientUserAPI` extends "Client" then the `__init__` method creates an infinite loop
2. If `ClientUserAPI` extends "object" then it won't directly have access  to the `self.user` and `self.pass` variables. This means I must create `__init__` methods on both of the helper classes which do nothing but assign `self.user` and `self.pass`. This is redundant not only in code, but also in memory

Is there a better solution?

Comment: What you have looks fine. Why would `ClientUserAPI` need access to `self.user`?

Comment: If you insist on the notation `client.users...`, then `users` must be an object, meaning an independent class, meaning you must implement it as standalone class. The `Client` class would then merely compose two of those independent classes into one `client` object. There's no need for it to be the parent class of anything. Memory consumption is pretty irrelevant with these values.

Comment: In other languages like e.g. Java you could create inner classes but objects of these would internally also hold a reference to the outer object. In Python you should do the same, but with explicit constructor parameter.

Comment: Only alternative would be to create an object on demand each time the attributes `users` or `posts` are requested but this would need CPU instead of memory.

Comment: `ClientUserAPI` needs access to `self.user` because the user and password must be passed to the HTTP API when a request is made. Therefore `ClientUserAPI.create` must send off an HTTP request with the username and password

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Client:
  def __init__(self):
    self.users = ClientUserAPI(self)
    self.posts = ClientPostAPI(self)

class ClientUserAPI:
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

class ClientPostAPI:
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
```